# Why in this pentagon, does the triangle and the square above it have the same size?

Tags: geometry

The red straight lines are parallel to each other, so are the green ones.
F and G are midpoints of the respective stretches.

[image]

Here another picture:
[image]

Why does the square and the triangle have the same size?

Comment: Could you add some context, such as what you have tried, where it came from, motivation, etc. This will help us answer your question and prevent it from being put on-hold.

Comment: As a rule, don't use colors to communicate on the internet. Some people are colorblind. I'm not, but it was hard for me to see which were red. Just name the parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Every convex trapezoid has two diagonals that intersect in the same ratio. The diagonals divide the trapezoid into four triangles, two of which are similar to each other and two of which are equal in area.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack. You have posted three separate answers, which is most unusual. Can you concentrate on writing one high-quality answer? Don't rely too much on the picture, we want to read some explanation also.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.

Maybe this can help a bit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

The areas are also the same size, if the circle doesn't go through point A and B.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).